Typeface.createFromAsset causing app crash on button click
I'm trying to set a custom font to a TextView in my Android app using Kotlin. I've placed the font file (iran_sans.tff) in the assets folder and am using the following code:
binding.button.setOnClickListener {
    val typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(assets, "iran_sans.tff")
    binding.textView.typeface = typeFace
}

However, every time I click the button, the app crashes. I've verified that the font file is correctly placed in the assets folder.
Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with the crash: https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-debug-001.html. If you do not understand the stack trace, edit your question to include the stack trace, along with whatever code of yours is referenced in the stack trace.
